# Change the opacity based on edge weight in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, transparency, opacity

I want to change the opacity of the edge based on the weight in a directed network. This is the code I found and changed a bit but it doesn't work, it still gives the same opacity. Any suggestions?

```
A = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[2, 0, 3],[5, 0, 0]])
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
layout = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, layout, with_labels=True)

for edge in G.edges(data="weight"):
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, layout, edgelist=[edge], alpha = (edge[2]/10))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you call `nx.draw` before drawing your edges. Instead draw your edges first and then draw your nodes.
See code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[2, 0, 3],[5, 0, 0]])
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
layout = nx.spring_layout(G)

for edge in G.edges(data="weight"):
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, layout, edgelist=[edge], alpha = (edge[2]/10))

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, layout)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,layout)
plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: How can I show the name on the nodes as well?

Comment: You can use `nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,layout)` (see doc [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_labels.html#)). And see edit of my answer.